Excel using Java Script to identify speculated cost in workbook
Hello so I have a excel workbook that automatically adds reports via power automate and Microsoft forms. But people would always spell words differently or write things like mouse & keyboard and 5 & 3. here's a quick run down of all the tables I assumed it would be good to use the excel script as I couldn't get the vda macro to work. Also be aware this excel is constantly updated with these automatic reports from forms
ReportsTable, A user puts in a report the Number of Equipment is saved in J and the Equipment name is saved in K.
SplittingTable, If a user puts in for example 5 & 3 and then Keyboard & mouse it splits the result into before & AG, after & AH - Before & name AI, after & Name AJ.
MappingTable, If a user spells the equipment in a different way for example Keyboards there is a mappingtable with the variation AP and the Common Name AQ, this connects to a macro that should perform a fuzzy match.
PriceTable, There is also the PriceTable which has the Equipment Name AA and the adjacent Price AB.
Finally there is the speculated Cost T, this should take the name of equipment compare it to the price then multiply it based on the quantity by making use of the SplittingTable results matching it with the macro table so that it can then get the price.
I've attached some images of the tables if that helps.
ReportsTable J and K

SplittingTable

MappingTable

PriceTable

Cost T Row

this is what i've wrote but I can't get it to work, if anyone has any ideas it would be appreciated, I know I could do this manually but since the reports are automatically added thought i'd try something.
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Get the worksheet
    let damagedEquipmentSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Damaged Equipment");
    let costSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Cost");

    // Check if worksheets are found
    if (!damagedEquipmentSheet || !costSheet) {
        return; // Exit the function if either worksheet is not found
    }

    // Function to handle changes in Damaged Equipment
    function handleReportChange() {
        let reportsRange = damagedEquipmentSheet.getRange("AG2:AH1000");
        let values = reportsRange.getValues();

        // Loop through the values
        for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            let numEquipment = parseFloat(values[i][0]?.toString()); // Ensure numEquipment is parsed as a number
            let equipmentName = values[i][1]?.toString(); // Ensure equipmentName is a string

            if (!equipmentName) {
                continue; // Skip the current iteration if equipmentName is undefined
            }

            // Get price for equipment name from PriceTable
            let price = getPriceFromPriceTable(equipmentName);

            // If price not found, try fuzzy matching using MappingTable
            if (!price) {
                let mappedName = getMappedNameFromMappingTable(equipmentName);
                if (mappedName) {
                    price = getPriceFromPriceTable(mappedName);
                }
            }

            // If price found, calculate speculated cost and update Speculated Cost sheet
            if (price) {
                let speculatedCost = numEquipment * price;
                costSheet.getRange(`T${i + 2}`).setValue(speculatedCost.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    // Calls the handleReportChange function
    handleReportChange();
}

// Function to get price for equipment name from PriceTable
function getPriceFromPriceTable(equipmentName: string): number {
    // Implementation omitted for brevity
}

// Function to get mapped equipment name from MappingTable
function getMappedNameFromMappingTable(equipmentName: string): string {
    // Implementation omitted for brevity
}


"This is what i've wrote but I can't get it to work" - could you be more specific? And maybe show us some input and expected output for your code? (I'm not sure how Excel works with JS, but a console.log(JSON.stringify(workbook)) would help a lot) It would be a lot easier to work with and test if we have some data.

I attached the input in the post as images, first time using Stack so let me know if they aren't attached.
Output is meant that for each report/row added to the reporttable will then calculate each cost by comparing to the price sheet & multiplying by the quantity, issue that people would spell things wrong so had to make mappingtable and also table to split the reports if they said something like keyboard & mouse
Then Issues with excel formula so I thought I'd try the newer script/automated tasks.
I'll try get something simillar to console.log(JSON.stringify(workbook)) because not on excel

https://docs.google.com/document/d/12ZycnsLBbT9LkFZANDDnAuJ4e_PnYYl04ZymIQsiRJY/edit?usp=sharing
I believe this is basically the same as console.log(JSON.stringify(workbook))  but if i'm incorrect let me know
I had to clear emails and names for data protection

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
